# Passing temporary std::string to boost::regex_match

Tags: c++, regex, boost

I want to parse a string of integer pairs into numbers. I use this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>

int main()
{
    boost::regex reg( "(\\d+):(\\d+)" );

    std::string test = "1:2 3:4 5:6";

    boost::sregex_token_iterator end;
    for( boost::sregex_token_iterator i( test.begin(), test.end(), reg ); i != end; ++i ) {
        boost::smatch what;
        if( boost::regex_match( i->str(), what, reg ) )
            std::cout << "found: \"" << what[1].str() << "\":\"" << what[2].str() << "\"" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Expected output:

```
found: "1":"2"
found: "3":"4"
found: "5":"6"
```

What I got with boost 1.52 compiled by gcc 4.7.2:

```
found: "2":"2"
found: "4":"4"
found: "6":"6"
```

boost 1.52 clang 3.2:

```
found: "":"2"
found: "":"4"
found: "":"6"
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: For what it's worth, `std::regex` as implemented in clang++/libc++ prints the expected output.

Comment: @Cubbi it still could be UB, unless they changed how smatch stores subexpressions' results

Answer (score 4):

Thanks from hint from Fraser, one possible solution is:

```
for( boost::sregex_token_iterator i( test.begin(), test.end(), reg ); i != end; ++i ) {
    boost::smatch what;
    const std::string &str = i->str(); 
    if( boost::regex_match( str, what, reg ) )
       std::cout << "found: \"" << what[1].str() << "\":\"" << what[2].str() << "\"" << std::endl;
}
```

So problem comes from the fact that i->str() calls boost::sub_match method:

```
basic_string<value_type> str()const;
```

and it returns std::string by value. So temporary of std::string passed to regex_match and boost::smatch object actually remembers positions in original string, which is actually destroyed after boost::regex_match finishes.
Similar problem can be reproduced as this:

```
std::string function();
boost::smatch what;
if( boost::regex_match( function(), what, reg ) ) ...
```

or I believe such code is vulnerable as well:

```
boost::smatch what;
if( boost::regex_match( std::string( "abc" ), what, reg ) ) ...
```

I am not sure how this situation can be prevented at compile time and should it be considered as a bug. std::regex_match seems to have the same signature, does this problem exist there?

Comment: This problem exists with `std::regex` as well, because `match_results` is defined to hold iterators into the string passed to `regex_match`, and they will be invalidated when it is destructed.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know the details of what Boost has now, but I don't think it affects this. I also don't know why you're getting the funky results after that call to `regex_match`, but that's not needed; the `token_iterator` has already done that match, so all you need is

```
std::cout << (*i)[1].str() << ':' << (*i)[2].str() << std::endl;
```

or, if you prefer:

```
std::cout << i->str(1) << ':' << i->str(2) << std::endl;
```

Note that this is C++11. It should work with Boost, too, but I haven't tried it.

Comment: error: type 'boost::sregex_token_iterator' (aka 'regex_token_iterator<std::string::const_iterator>') does not provide a subscript operator

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure about the implementation details of Boost.Regex, but it appears that copying the dereferenced `sregex_token_iterator` inside the `for` loop to a temporary `std::string` fixes the issue:

```
std::string copied( i->str() );
boost::smatch what;
if( boost::regex_match( copied, what, reg ) ) {
    std::cout << "found: \"" << what[1].str() << "\":\"" << what[2].str() << "\"" << std::endl;
}
```

Hopefully someone with better knowledge of Boost.Regex can give a better answer.

Comment: Good catch, thanks! Actually copy is not necessary - const reference is enough.